# Jquery menu creation question

Tags: jquery, menu

I am creating a simple script using jquery,when the user clicks on a link it slides down.
How can I  close/slideup the  other lists automatically that have already expanded, when i click on another lists to slides down.

i.e When one block slides down, if any other that may be open should slide up. Can someone show me step by step to how to do this?

thanks

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu ul').hide();
  $('.menu .arrowUp').click(function() {
  $(this).find(".third-level").toggle();
  });
});

<ul class="menu">
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link1</a>
    <ul class="third-level" >             
    <!-- third level non-active -->
     <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/view/page/bache/16425">Some Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link2</a>
    <ul class="third-level" >             
    <!-- third level non-active -->
     <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/view/page/bache/16425">some Links 2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link3</a>
                                    <ul class="third-level" >
                                      <!-- third level non-active -->
                                      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/view/page/bache/16417">Agricultural Commodities</a></li>
                                        <!-- third level non-active -->
                                      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/view/page/bache/16418">Sugar</a></li>
                                     <!-- third level non-active -->
                                      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/view/page/bache/16419">Coffee</a></li>
                                      <!-- third level non-active -->
                                      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/view/page/bache/16420">Energy</a></li>
                                      <!-- third level non-active -->
                                      <li class="arrowUp"><a href="/view/page/bache/16421">Financials</a></li>
                                    </ul>
</li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link4</a></li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link5</a></li>
<li class="arrowUp"><a href="#">link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) what you want?

Comment: somewhat but not exactly, i am also trying to drill down the list and  highlight the link the user has clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to hide them all again before you toggle the one you want

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu ul').hide();
  $('.menu .arrowUp').click(function() {
      $('.menu ul').hide();
      $(this).find(".third-level").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks that worked. any idea why when u click on the links it tends to jump to the top of the page? and how I could higlight the child list when clicked?

Comment: after the `toggle` just put `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

I know I just commented, but I might as well post as an answer:

## Don't bother reinventing the wheel:

you can use the [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).